# Proof by induction: exponentiation of a square matrix

Tags: matrices, proof-writing, induction

I am currently stuck on the following problem, and I was wondering if anyone could assist me.

> Prove the following using induction. For all $n\in\mathbb N$
>   $$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 9 \\ -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}^n 
> = \begin{pmatrix}1-3n & 9n \\ -n & 1+3n\end{pmatrix}$$
>   Hint: let $P(n)$ be the proposition that the above equation holds for $n$.

Thus far I have confirmed the base case to be true, but I am not sure where to go from there. I know that I am meant to assume that $P$ is true for $n+1$, but I am not sure how that benefits me here.

P.S.: I would include a picture of the base case, but it seems kind of trivial.

Comment: Nope, you're NOT meant to **assume** it true for $n+1$! You're meant to assume it true for $n$ and then derive a conclusion it is also true for $n+1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite obvious whether $0\in\mathbb N$, anyway you can either check the proposition for $n=0$ or for $n=1$ as a base case.

You know (I hope)
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 9 \\ -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}^{n+1} = \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 9 \\ -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}^n \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 9 \\ -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$
So you can use the assumption
$$\begin{pmatrix}-2 & 9 \\ -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}^n 
= \begin{pmatrix}1-3n & 9n \\ -n & 1+3n\end{pmatrix}$$
to get
$$\begin{pmatrix}1-3(n+1) & 9(n+1) \\ -(n+1) & 1+3(n+1)\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1-3n & 9n \\ -n & 1+3n\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}-2 & 9 \\ -1 & 4\end{pmatrix}$$
If you verify the above is true, you'll get the conclusion the inductive hypothesis is satisfied, hence the whole statement is true.